# Remove xml tag that contains specific value with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have configuration file

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>name1</name>
    <value>value1</value>
    <description>desc1</description>
</property>
 <property>
    <name>name2</name>
    <value>valueToRemove</value>
    <description>desc2</description>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>name3</name>
    <value>value3</value>
    <description>desc3</description>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>name3</name>
    <value>valueToRemove</value>
    <description>desc4</description>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>name5</name>
    <value>valu5</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

I want to remove all property tags that contains value valueToRemove.

I want next output

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>name1</name>
    <value>value1</value>
    <description>desc1</description>
</property>
 <property>
    <name>name3</name>
    <value>value3</value>
    <description>desc3</description>
 </property>
 <property>
    <name>name5</name>
    <value>valu5</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```

Next bash script removes only lines with value tags.

```
sed -i "/[<property>].*valueToRemove.*[<\/property]>/d"  "test"
```

Help me, please, I am very new to bash and regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Answer (score 1):

Never parse XML with regexes. They are [just the wrong tools for XML and its variants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg/702222).

Really, having an XML parser isn't hard nowadays. There's plenty of libraries and tools to do so; especially if you're new to bash programming, why would you use that?

The only difference from a OS perspective from a bash script and e.g. a python script is their first line,

```
#!/path/to/program/that/will/interpret/this/script
```

and for you it's that you could use any script language, e.g. python, that has a good XML library. With python and lxml, it's a few lines of code, and you'd be pretty sure that even the least `sed`-understandable XML comes out proper, as long as it's valid XML.

tl;dr: **Don't use regexes/sed to parse XML. Use an XML parser. Bash is just a script interpreter, and there are far more potent scripting languages to deal with such tasks.**